# How get data of model association rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

How can i get data of model association

this are my models.

**user.rb**

```
has_many :movie
has_many :quality
has_many :option
```

**movie.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :quality, :dependent => :destroy
```

**quality.rb**

```
belongs_to :movie
belongs_to :user
has_many :option
```

**option.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :quality
has_one :movie, :through => :quality
```

this is my controller

**movie_controller.rb**

```
def show
   @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
end
```

In my view i have this.

```
-@movie.qualities.option do |o|
  =o.name
```

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Gxgf.png)

I want to get all the names of the qualities of a movie.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change all has many relationship to plural

```
has_many :movies
has_many :qualities
has_many :options
# etc
```

and option belongs_to movie

Comment: I guess option belongs_to movie

Comment: Nothing   :(:(:( :(

Answer (score 0):

Your final code should look like this

**user.rb**

```
has_many :movies
has_many :qualities, through: :movies
has_many :options, through: :qualities
```

**movie.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :qualities, dependent: :destroy
```

**quality.rb**

```
belongs_to :movie
has_one :user, through: :movie
has_many :options
```

**option.rb**

```
belongs_to :quality
has_one :user, through: :quality
has_one :movie, through: :quality
```

**movie_controller.rb**

```
def show
   @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
end
```

View should be like this.

```
- @movie.qualities.each do |quality|
  - quality.options.each do |option|
    = option.name
```

Cheers :)